# Как отредактировать отправленное ботом сообщение в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть код с помощью которого бот отправляет фото пользователю вместе с подписью и Inline клавиатурой, после необходимо изменить в ранее отправленном сообщении Inline клавиатуру и подпись, как это можно сделать?

Код с помощью которого отправляю фото пользователям:

```
x = await bot.send_photo(
                chat_id=userId,
                photo=image,
                caption=message_text,
                reply_markup=keyboard,
                parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
            )
```

Код с помощью которого пытаюсь изменить подпись и клавиатуру ранее отправленного сообщения:

```
x = await bot.edit_message_media(
                    media=image,
                    chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                    message_id=lastBotWordMessageId,
                    caption=answerCheckMessage,
                    reply_markup=answerCheckKeyboard
                )
```

Также хотел бы, чтобы вы отправили пример кода по изменению простого сообщения без фото, но с подписью и Inline клавиатурой.

Comment: Покажите переменную image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для изменения `caption` Вы можете передать в Ваш `InputMedia` объект параметр `caption`. Вот Вам небольшой пример:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["photo"])
async def photo(message: Message):
    file_path = "files/foods/borsch.jpg"
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="I want a new photo!", callback_data="update_photo")
    )
    file = InputFile(file_path)
    
    await bot.send_photo(
        message.chat.id,
        photo=file,
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
        caption="Test caption!",
    )


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="update_photo")
async def photo_update(query: CallbackQuery):
    file_path = "files/foods/pelmeni.png"
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Updated button", callback_data="dont_click_me")
    )
    file = InputMedia(media=InputFile(file_path), caption="Updated caption :)")

    await query.message.edit_media(file, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Сообщение при вызове команды:

[image: Сообщение при вызове команды:]

Сообщение при нажатии на кнопку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Теперь появилась необходимость изменить фото на другое, которое хранится на серверах телеграма, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отредактировать подпись и Inline клавиатуру под фото:

```
x = await bot.edit_message_caption(
                    chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                    message_id=lastBotWordMessageId,
                    caption=answerCheckMessage,
                    reply_markup=answerCheckKeyboard
                )
```